# Android: Streaming mpeg audio from an internet radio station?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, mpeg, internet-radio

I've looked everywhere but apparently this isn't a very common problem. I'm working on an app to stream audio/mpeg formatted music from an internet radio station. Just pointing a MediaPlayer at the url only yields 60 millisecond sound clips, I'm assuming because mpeg isn't supported as a format. Changing the format the server streams isn't feasible, is there a way to convert on the fly or something? Or is there an easier way?

Thanks.